# Renaming file to .py extension does nothing

Tags: python, file-extension

I would not like to ask such a dumb question but when I rename my file to whatever.py it doesn't do anything.

[image: screenshot showing "bot.py" file in Windows Explorer]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Lantz Greer: Maybe you should have state what condition (OS, what u use to do the changes ie Window Explorer etc)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, you have "File name extensions" hidden, and the filename is actually `bot.py.txt`. [Turn file name extensions on in Windows Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/) in the **View** tab, then rename it to `bot.py`.